# how remove next append on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a problem with my code; when I `mouseenter` an element, a toolbar is appended to this element, but when I `mouseleave` from the toolbar to the element, the toolbar is appended again. How can I prevent this re-appending?

```
$('.el').on('mouseenter', function(e){

  var toolbar = $('<div class="toolbar"><span>leave toolbar to element</span></div>');  

    setTimeout(function(){
        toolbar.addClass('widget-over');
    },100);

    $('body').prepend(toolbar);

    toolbar.css({
        left:$('.el').offset().left,
        top:$('.el').offset().top - toolbar.height() - 20
    });

    $('.el').on('mouseleave',function(e){
        if ($(e.relatedTarget).closest(toolbar).length) return;
        toolbar.removeClass('widget-over');
        toolbar.remove();
    });

    toolbar.on('mouseleave',function(e){
        toolbar.remove();
    });
});
```

Big thanks to community for answers! exactly [Jeremy Thille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille), [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) and [Jivings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334274/jivings)

1. Problem fiddle -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/)
2. Solution fiddle -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/2/)

Comment: @codeMan try to mouseleave toolbar to "text", you will see that toolbar appends again with animation, don't undestand how to remove this .

Comment: I am on Firefox 35.0.1 and it works as expected.

Comment: @Anton yes, it works, but i want to remove "re" append when `mouseleave` toolbar to element, try, you'll see that animation play again

Comment: Your code looks so, so complicated and twisted to me... adding an element on mouseenter, applying a class after a timeout, removing the element on mouseleave... Dude, you can just use `$('el').hover( function{toolbar.fadeIn();}, function{toolbar.fadeOut();})`

Comment: @JeremyThille i can't using simple `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` because i want to use custom animation, but thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle just shows a 0.15s fadeIn and fadeOut...

Comment: @JeremyThille fiddle - yes, own code - no :)

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mxgbaqrL/2/

Comment: How about this kind of approach? http://jsfiddle.net/ms2L2wcr/

Comment: @ArunPJohny it works, but i've got many toolbars on page, and with your code, when i `mouseenter` next element, toolbar don't appear ( toolbar append only if i firstly `mousenter` `body` and only then next element )

Comment: @JeremyThille you send me fiddle from my question :)

Comment: Haha oops sorry, wrong paste :) Here's the right one http://jsfiddle.net/4155jyn3/ , and also try with plugins like Qtip : http://jsfiddle.net/79xqxesc/1/

Comment: @JeremyThille if i don't find answer, maybe will use your plugin :( but don't want to load any libraries for things like this :(

Comment: Well, we gave you many solutions here. Other guys fixed your code, and I proposed other approaches. Why don't you want to load plugins? Someone else had the same problem, thought about it, figured it out, and made a free plugin that solves the problem. So you don't have to reinvent the wheel, it's clean and cross-browser.

Comment: @JeremyThille i'm waiting comment from "Arun P Johny" - his solution most interesting, but works with small bug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble was that you were creating your event handlers each time there was a `mouseover`. I've split them up to make it simpler, and that seems to have fixed your bug:

```
var toolbar = $('<div class="toolbar"><span>leave toolbar to element</span></div>');  
toolbar.on('mouseleave',function(e){
    toolbar.remove();
});    

var enter = function(e) {

    setTimeout(function(){
        toolbar.addClass('widget-over');
    },100);

    $('body').prepend(toolbar);

    toolbar.css({
        left: $el.offset().left,
        top: $el.offset().top - toolbar.height() - 20
    });    
};

var leave = function(e){
    if ($(e.relatedTarget).closest(toolbar).length) return;
    toolbar.removeClass('widget-over');
    toolbar.remove();
}

var $el = $('.el')
    .on('mouseenter', enter)
    .on('mouseleave', leave);
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/2/

Comment: now it works, big thanks, but now ( with your code ) if i mouseleave from toolbar to body, toolbar doesn't remove, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/4/