# how to remove appended toolbar on mouseleave to body or another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431036/how-remove-next-append-on-mouseleave) answer by [Jivings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334274/jivings) was not given full, and i've got problem with his answer. When I `mouseenter` an element, a toolbar is appended to this element, but when I mouseleave from the toolbar to the **body** ( or **another** element but **not** current! ), the toolbar doesn't dissapear. How i can remove toolbar on mouseleave to body?

```
var toolbar = $('<div class="toolbar"><span>leave toolbar to element</span></div>');  
toolbar.on('mouseleave',function(e){
    toolbar.remove();
});    

var enter = function(e) {

    setTimeout(function(){
        toolbar.addClass('widget-over');
    },100);

    $('body').prepend(toolbar);

    toolbar.css({
        left: $el.offset().left,
        top: $el.offset().top - toolbar.height() - 20
    });    
};

var leave = function(e){
    if ($(e.relatedTarget).closest(toolbar).length) return;
    toolbar.removeClass('widget-over');
    toolbar.remove();
}

var $el = $('.el')
    .on('mouseenter', enter)
    .on('mouseleave', leave);
```

Problem fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically removing and adding the element with a new class and bind.

```js
$(function () {
var toolbar = $('<div class="toolbar"><span>leave toolbar to body and mouseenter element again</span></div>');   

var enter = function(e) {
    console.log('enter')
    setTimeout(function(){
        toolbar.addClass('widget-over');
    },500);

    $('body').prepend(toolbar.on('mouseleave',function(e){ 
        $(this).removeClass("widget-over");
        $(this).remove();        
        console.log('toolbar out');
    }));

    toolbar.css({
        left: $el.offset().left,
        top: $el.offset().top - toolbar.height() - 20
    });  


};

var leave = function(e){
    if ($(e.relatedTarget).closest(toolbar).length) return;
    toolbar.removeClass('widget-over');
    toolbar.remove();
}

var $el = $('.el')
    .on('mouseenter', enter)
    .on('mouseleave', leave) ;
});
```

Comment: one more bug :) mouseenter on element, then on toolbar and then again on element. you will see strange "blink" toolbar effect. how to fix this last bug?

Comment: Well I think you should put your toolbar inside the ".el" div class, and just use the mouseleave event for that div. 

That way you don't have to deal with two events that are running one after another, one removing the div, and one appending it again, causing the blink.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your this code

```
toolbar.on('mouseleave',function(e){
    toolbar.remove();
});
```

with this code

```
$(document).on("mouseleave",".toolbar",function(){
    $(".toolbar").remove();
});
```

what happen here is your toolbar is created dynamically through jquery. that's why mouseleave event is not applied.

if you want to apply event on every dynamically created element then please use below syntax.

```
$(document).on("eventname","selector",function(){
    // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: please, wait a minute, trying! :)

Comment: works great. but have some problem, when toolbar appear again, he appear without `addClass' , i'm trying to remove class and have new problem,try to leave toolbar on element, you will see that animation works again: http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/8/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are binding the event on the toolbar just the first time your prepending the toolbar into the body.

The correct way is to preppend the toolbar with the new onmouseleave bind. Like this.

```
$(function () {
var toolbar = $('<div class="toolbar"><span>leave toolbar to body</span></div>');   

var enter = function(e) {
    console.log('enter')
    setTimeout(function(){
        toolbar.addClass('widget-over');
    },100);

    $('body').prepend(toolbar.on('mouseleave',function(e){        
        $(this).detach();        
        console.log('toolbar out');
    }));

    toolbar.css({
        left: $el.offset().left,
        top: $el.offset().top - toolbar.height() - 20
    });  


};

var leave = function(e){
    if ($(e.relatedTarget).closest(toolbar).length) return;
    toolbar.removeClass('widget-over');
    toolbar.remove();
}

var $el = $('.el')
    .on('mouseenter', enter)
    .on('mouseleave', leave) ;
```

});

Hope it helps!

Comment: works fine! **but** as you can see in your answer ( as in previous anwser ) when toolbar append, he append without any animation, he append **already** with class, how to fix this bug?

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I don't understand what are your trying to achieve here.

Comment: look: http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/10/ .Try to leave toolbar to body and then mouseenter element. you will see that toolbar append to element without `setTimeout(function()` animation.

Comment: Oh ok, Then the problem is that we are not removing the class on the mouseleave bind function in the toolbar element.

Just remove the class inside that function.
`

<pre>
    $('body').prepend(toolbar.on('mouseleave',function(e){ 
        $(this).removeClass("widget-over");
        $(this).remove();        
        console.log('toolbar out');
    }));
`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3r8wrumL/11/ one more bug :) mouseenter on element, then on toolbar and then again on element. you will see strange "blink" toolbar effect. how to fix this last bug?